# charging in power off

Tags: ipad, charging

I am using ipad 1 and I have some charging problem in it so,I want to ask that is there any problem if I charge my ipad in **power off mode**.
If yes yes what can be the problems that can be seen in my ipad

Can I use Chinese chargers for charging it.

Comment: What are some of the problems you are having?

Answer (score 4):

You can charge your iPad 1 while in power off mode.

With regard to using a Chinese non-Apple branded charger, this is possible. However you should be aware that Apple's chargers are recommended. The price difference between a non-Apple branded charger and Apple's own charger is significant; that difference is because of Apple's design costs and additional safety features.

[Ken Shirriff's article](http://www.arcfn.com/2012/05/apple-iphone-charger-teardown-quality.html) showing the inside of an Apple iPhone charger demonstrates why the price difference exists.

Answer (score 0):

there are no problems with this. You can swap chargers however you want, although it is recommended that you use ones that are manufactured by apple.

Answer (score 0):

The iPad is designed to draw more than the 500mA specified for USB. It even exceeds past 1A that is not unusual anymore these days but still not exactly standard USB2 current.

So, with the Apple charger for the iPad you get 10W at 5V and 2A. With any iPhone charger the iPad will only receive 5W at 1A, and most USB2 ports only deliver 500mA, resulting in only 2.5W. The iPad will charge with all of these currents, but it will take longer the lower the current falls.

Make sure you get a charger that safely delivers at least 1A, better 2A.

And yes, you can charge it when its off. It should be even quicker than charging while turned on.